# cocos2d-iphone sprite sheet loading

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone

I have a problem while creating a button class for my game.
My button images are in a sprite sheet , witch I created in Zwoptex.
The problem is that the program crashes while loading the sprites.

Here is Buttons.h:

```
#import "CommonProtocols.h"
#import "GameObject.h"


@interface Buttons : CCSprite
{
    CCSprite *buttonSprite;
    ButtonTypes *buttonType;
    CCSpriteBatchNode *buttonsNode;
}
+(id)button;
-(id)initButtonWithType:(ButtonTypes)bType;

@property (readwrite,assign)CCSpriteBatchNode* buttonsNode;
@property (readwrite,assign)CCSprite *buttonSprite;
@property (readonly)ButtonTypes *buttonType;
@end
```

And here is the implementation:

```
#import "Buttons.h"

@implementation Buttons
@synthesize buttonSprite;
@synthesize buttonsNode;
@synthesize buttonType;
-(void)dealloc
{
    [buttonSprite release];
    [super dealloc];
}
+(id)button
{
    return [[[self alloc] init] autorelease];
}


-(id)initButtonWithType:(ButtonTypes)btype 
{
    if(self=[super init]){

    buttonsNode = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"Buttons.png"];
    [[self parent] addChild:buttonsNode];

    [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"Buttons.plist"];

    switch (btype)
    {
        case kFireButton:
            [self setButtonSprite:[CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"firebutton.png"]];
            [buttonsNode addChild:[self buttonSprite]];
            return self;
            break;

        case kLeftButton:
            [self setButtonSprite:[CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"leftbutton.png"]];
            [buttonsNode addChild:[self buttonSprite]];
            return self;
            break;

        case kRightButton:
            [self setButtonSprite:[CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"rightbutton.png"]];
            [buttonsNode addChild:[self buttonSprite]];
            return self;
            break;

        case kReplayButton:
            [self setButtonSprite:[CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"replaybutton.png"]];
            [buttonsNode addChild:[self buttonSprite]];
            return self;
            break;


        default:
            NSLog(@"NO button");
            break;

        }

    }
return self;
}
@end
```

The program crashes when I elsewhere call this methods:

```
 Buttons *myButton = [[Buttons button] initButtonWithType:kFireButton];
        [self addChild:myButton];
```

And here is what the program outputs:

```
cocos2d: CCSpriteFrameCache: Frame 'firebutton.png' not found

*** Assertion failure in +[CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:],
```

And finally here is the plist that Zwoptex generated:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>frames</key>
    <dict>

        <key>firebutton.png</key>
        <dict>
            <key>aliases</key>
            <array>

            </array>
            <key>spriteColorRect</key>
            <string>{{1, 2}, {38, 40}}</string>
            <key>spriteOffset</key>
            <string>{0, 2}</string>
            <key>spriteSize</key>
            <string>{38, 40}</string>
            <key>spriteSourceSize</key>
            <string>{40, 48}</string>
            <key>spriteTrimmed</key>
            <true/>
            <key>textureRect</key>
            <string>{{51, 1}, {38, 40}}</string>
            <key>textureRotated</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>

        <key>leftbutton.png</key>
        <dict>
            <key>aliases</key>
            <array>

            </array>
            <key>spriteColorRect</key>
            <string>{{1, 0}, {46, 47}}</string>
            <key>spriteOffset</key>
            <string>{0, -0}</string>
            <key>spriteSize</key>
            <string>{46, 47}</string>
            <key>spriteSourceSize</key>
            <string>{48, 47}</string>
            <key>spriteTrimmed</key>
            <true/>
            <key>textureRect</key>
            <string>{{1, 52}, {46, 47}}</string>
            <key>textureRotated</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>

        <key>replaybutton.png</key>
        <dict>
            <key>aliases</key>
            <array>

            </array>
            <key>spriteColorRect</key>
            <string>{{1, 0}, {46, 47}}</string>
            <key>spriteOffset</key>
            <string>{0, -0}</string>
            <key>spriteSize</key>
            <string>{46, 47}</string>
            <key>spriteSourceSize</key>
            <string>{48, 47}</string>
            <key>spriteTrimmed</key>
            <true/>
            <key>textureRect</key>
            <string>{{49, 52}, {46, 47}}</string>
            <key>textureRotated</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>

        <key>rightbutton.png</key>
        <dict>
            <key>aliases</key>
            <array>

            </array>
            <key>spriteColorRect</key>
            <string>{{1, 0}, {46, 47}}</string>
            <key>spriteOffset</key>
            <string>{0, -0}</string>
            <key>spriteSize</key>
            <string>{46, 47}</string>
            <key>spriteSourceSize</key>
            <string>{48, 47}</string>
            <key>spriteTrimmed</key>
            <true/>
            <key>textureRect</key>
            <string>{{1, 1}, {48, 49}}</string>
            <key>textureRotated</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>

    </dict>
    <key>metadata</key>
    <dict>
        <key>version</key>
        <string>1.5.5</string>
        <key>format</key>
        <integer>3</integer>
        <key>size</key>
        <string>{128, 128}</string>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Buttons</string>
        <key>premultipliedAlpha</key>
        <false/>
        <key>target</key>
        <dict>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>default</string>
            <key>textureFileName</key>
            <string>Buttons</string>
            <key>textureFileExtension</key>
            <string>.png</string>
            <key>coordinatesFileName</key>
            <string>Buttons</string>
            <key>coordinatesFileExtension</key>
            <string>.plist</string>
            <key>premultipliedAlpha</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm ... looks ok to me. Probably not finding the .plist . Verify that the .plist is a member of your target, and that the filename case is correct in your resources directory.

Also, on this line :

```
[[self parent] addChild:buttonsNode];
```

not certain that parent is set when you call the init method.

Edit : put a breakpoint on the line where you add sprite frames from the plist. Step into it until you are HERE , in CCSpriteFrameCache's code :

```
-(void) addSpriteFramesWithFile:(NSString*)plist
{
    NSAssert(plist, @"plist filename should not be nil");

    if( ! [loadedFilenames_ member:plist] ) {

        NSString *path = [[CCFileUtils sharedFileUtils] fullPathFromRelativePath:plist];
        NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];

        NSString *texturePath = nil;
....
```

and verify that dict is not nil. The method used by cocos2d for loading a directory silently 'fails', ie returns a nil Dictionary object if the file does not exist.  If the file exists the problem is something else. If dict is nil, well ... keep looking in your project setup until you find the issue, either with file naming (be mindful of the case for the filename in project and in finder : MUST be the same), or the file is not a member of your target. Also, if you enabled HD for your project, make certain that the plist is "Buttons-hd.plist", same for the texture (Buttons-hd.png). Same, CCSpriteBatchNode does 'nothing' with a missing texture, fails silently.

Comment: The plist is in the resource/Plists library and the .png in the resources library but still not works.
I have no idea, what can be the problem...